# Flexible way of passing key event to currently selected tab, using notebook from tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, tabs, bind

As far as I can tell, I cannot bind a keypress to the current tab since it won't have the focus. I was imagining that I could do a bind_all instead and then it would call a function in the tab's child. Something like this,

```
class A(Frame):
  ...
  def onSpacebar(self):
    <do something>

class B(Frame):
  ...
  def onSpacebar(self):
    <do something>


class Tabbed(Frame):
  def __init__(self, **kw):
    ...
    self.nb = Notebook(self)
    self.nb.add(A(nb), text=A.getTitle())
    self.nb.add(B(nb), text=B.getTitle())

    self.bind_all("<space>", self.onSpacebar)

  def onSpacebar(self,e=None):
    self.nb.select().child().onSpacebar() <---something equivalent
```

Is it possible to reference object A or B in something like this way?

I know there are plenty of ways of accomplishing this with using the index and saving off A and B, using dicts, etc.

This is a simple example for illustration. Imagine if there were 20 tabs, and some tabs may not be added, depending on some parameter. Therefore, not depending on tab names or indexes would be great. Or maybe there is completely better solution for binding the spacebar(or any other key) to a tab.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried [`focus_set()`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.focus_set-method) method?

Comment: The issue is, the user is going to need the focus in a Spinbox so they can manipulate the value and then quickly hit the spacebar, change the value, hit the spacebar,  etc. The spacebar also has to work from other controls in the tab.